# Integrity Constraint Violation with POST on PRIMARY

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

With Symfony 3.2 (running on Apache with PHP-FPM) we offer a REST API which allows to POST new entities via JSON payload in the request.

We don't have a high traffic on our API but in this specific case our frontend fires > 20 POST requests towards our API *at the same time*.

Today for the very first time (this app is running since 3 years) we received in production the following error message for one of these requests:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5372' for key 'PRIMARY' in /home/vcap/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php` (...)
>
> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO our_entity (ourfield1, ourfield2, ourfield3,...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,...

unfortunately our logging in production stops here which is another issue

We don't do

1. any updates here (not before and not after)
2. we have no additional unique constraint validations
3. we use the *standard* Auto-ID-Generator against a *standard* MariaDB database
4. of course there was no entity existing with this ID in our database before

In the end it's a simple

```
// Step 1 - create and flush new Entity
$newEntity = new OurEntity();
$newEntity->setValues($valuesFromJsonPayload);
$em->persist($newEntity);
$em->flush();

// Step 2 - get ID and store it with another object

$em->refresh($newEntity);

$generatedId = $newEntity->getId();
$history = new History();
$history->setNewId($generatedId);
$em->persist($history);
$em->flush();
```

I don't even see why I would mention *Step 2* here because the issue obviously arises with the *Step 1* according to the error message.

After we asked our user to simple execute the same action again it worked like a charm.

Any ideas why that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit off topic, but:

I would not recommend using the database auto increment for IDs.

You could, for instance use [Uuid library](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid). The ID would be a random hashed string. Your entity object would have ID and be valid immediately upon instantiation. And you would not have to save it to database just to obtain the ID.

Just yesterday I gave a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211455/2484968). Have a look for the rest of the story and references.

Comment: thanks Duro, I am fully aware of the disadvantages of auto-generated incremental IDs vs UUIDs, in fact we're already moving towards it. but as you noticed this does not answer my question.